# How to make checkbox info append to email

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

I have 3 checkboxes on my contact form. The form works with exception to the checkboxes.. The boxes are selectable but once hitting the "submit" button the selection shows up on the "Thank you for you comment" page. I cannot figure out how to get the checkbox selection to appear in the actual email.

I have tried all sorts of php functions that I have found people to be using in forums and tutorials. Nothing appends the checkbox info to the email. I can't seem to find anyone who knows how to do this.

The 'implode' function does not work. The 'echo' function does not work. The 'array' function does not work. What could be going on?

Here is my html:

```
<section class="contact">   
    <form id="contact" action="html_form_send.php" method="post">
    <fieldset title="About you">
    <legend><span>About you</span></legend>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" tabindex="10"  class="txtinput" placeholder="Your name" required>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="20" class="txtinput" placeholder="valid email" required>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset title="Your turn">
      <legend><span>Your turn</span></legend>
    <p>What, exactly then, are you after?</p>
    <div>
        <div class="tag">Checkbox1</div>         
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1-1" name="option[ ]" class="regular-checkbox big-checkbox" value="salvation" /></input><label for="checkbox-1-1"></label>
   </div>
   <div>
        <div class="tag">Checkbox2</div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2-1" name="option[ ]" class="regular-checkbox big-checkbox" value="question" /><label for="checkbox-2-1"></label>
  </div>
  <div>
        <div class="tag">Checkbox3</div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-3-1" name="option[ ]" class="regular-checkbox big-checkbox" value="other" /><label for="checkbox-3-1"></label>
  </div>
       <label for="comment" class="inline"></label>
          <label for="discourse">Write your comments here</label>
         <textarea id="discourse" name="discourse" tabindex="30" class="txtinput" rows="7" placeholder="This is where your thoughts go">
         </textarea>

    <section id="buttons">
    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="resetbtn" class="resetbtn" value="Reset">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbtn" class="submitbtn" tabindex="40" value="Send away!">
    <br style="clear:both;">
    </section>
```

Here is my php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "email@email.org";

    $email_subject = "website feedback";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We're sorry, but there's errors found with the form you submitted.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['discourse'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $discourse = $_POST['discourse']; // not required   $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
   if(strlen($discourse) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($discourse)."\n";

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) //Checks if the send button is pressed
    {
        echo $_POST["name"]; //print your name
        echo $_POST["email"]; //print your email

        //check all the checkboxes if anyone is checked. this is a lot of work to do.
        //All checkboxes are checked one by one
    if(isset($_POST["salvation"]))
        echo $_POST["salvation"];

    if(isset($_POST["question"]))
        echo $_POST["question"];

    if(isset($_POST["other"]))
        echo $_POST["other"];    }
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) //Checks if the send button is pressed
   {
    echo $_POST["name"]; //print your name
    echo $_POST["email"]; //print your email

    if(isset($_POST["option"])) //checks if any interest is checked
    {
        foreach($_POST["option"] as $value) //Iterate the interest array and get the values
        {
            echo  $value;  //print the values          }         }     }


  // create email headers
  $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
  'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  }
  ?>

  <!-- place your own success html below -->
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for contacting us.');
        window.location = 'feedbackform.html';
        </script>    
  <?php
  die();
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div class="tag">Checkbox2</div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2-1" name="option1" class="regular-checkbox big-checkbox" value="yes" /><label for="checkbox-2-1"></label>
  </div>
```

Try naming each option checkbox then retrieve them as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['option1']) && $_POST['option1'] == 'yes'){
    echo "Yes, this was checked";
}else{
    echo "No, this wasn't checked";
}
```

What that if statement does is checks if that option is set, meaning has value, and grabs the value if it is set.  Then it outputs accordingly

Comment: I received the following error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected" which was pointing to <?php die(); ?> at the bottom of the php page. I have received this same error many times all day. Yet there are no errors with my php page UNTIL I add code for those checkboxes.

Comment: I won't directly spoonfeed you, since it's best to learn.  However, my code is demonstrating how to check for the boxes.  You may need to manipulate it a bit to fit directly into your code.

Comment: Oh, I realize that I have to fit the code to my form. I added another '}' because I thought that one was missing. Now there is no error message, however, the checkbox info is not appending to the email. It is showing up again on the 'Thank you for your comment' page instead. The email is still working but it only contains the name, email and comment -- no checkbox info.

Comment: Could the 'Message" text box area be interfering with the checkboxes? I am wondering because while the emails contain the above info, the 'Thank you for your comment' page is showing the name, email, and checkbox info, but no comment info. Yet, the text written in the message box is sending with the emails. Something is going on but I cannot figure out what or why.

Comment: I added this string to my php and now the checkbox 1, 2, and 3 show up in the email but not the values, or which one was selected. $email_message .= "checkbox-1-1: ".clean_string($option1)."\n";